# Implicit conversion failure from initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++

Consider the snippet:

```
#include <unordered_map>

void foo(const std::unordered_map<int,int> &) {}

int main()
{
        foo({});
}
```

This fails with GCC 4.9.2 with the message:

```
map2.cpp:7:19: error: converting to ‘const std::unordered_map<int, int>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map(std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::size_type, const hasher&, const key_equal&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::hasher = std::hash<int>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_equal = std::equal_to<int>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’
```

Testing with other compiler/library implementations:

- GCC < 4.9 accepts this without complaining,
- Clang 3.5 with libstdc++ fails with a similar message,
- Clang 3.5 with libc++ accepts this,
- ICC 15.something accepts this (not sure which standard library it is using).

A couple of more baffling points:

- replacing `std::unordered_map` with `std::map` makes the error go away,
- replacing `foo({})` with foo `foo({{}})` also makes the error go away.

Also, replacing `{}` with a non-empty initializer list works as expected in all cases.

So my main questions are:

- who is right here? Is the code above well-formed?
- What does the syntax with double curly braces `foo({{}})` exactly do to make the error go away?

**EDIT** fixed a couple of typos.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The indirect initialization syntax with a *braced-init-list* your code is using is called *copy-list-initialization*.

The overload resolution procedure selecting the best viable constructor for that case is described in the following section of the C++ Standard:

> #### § 13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization `[over.match.list]`
>
> 1. When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor
>      in two phases:
>
>    — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>
>    — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed. [ *Note:* This differs from other situations (13.3.1.3, 13.3.1.4), where only converting constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This restriction only applies if this initialization is part of the final result of overload resolution. *— end note* ].

According to that, an *initializer-list-constructor* (the one callable with a single argument matching the constructor's parameter of type `std::initializer_list<T>`) is usually preferred to other constructors, **but not if a default-constructor is available**, and the *braced-init-list* used for *list-initialization* **is empty**.

What is important here, the set of constructors of the standard library's containers has changed between C++11 and C++14 due to [**LWG issue 2193**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2193). In case of `std::unordered_map`, for the sake of our analysis, we are interested in the following difference:

*C++11:*

```
explicit unordered_map(size_type n = /* impl-defined */,
                     const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                     const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                     const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());

unordered_map(initializer_list<value_type> il,
            size_type n = /* impl-defined */,
            const hasher& hf = hasher(),
            const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
            const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

*C++14:*

```
unordered_map();

explicit unordered_map(size_type n,
                     const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                     const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                     const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());

unordered_map(initializer_list<value_type> il,
            size_type n = /* impl-defined */,
            const hasher& hf = hasher(),
            const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
            const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

In other words, there is a different *default constructor* (the one that can be called without arguments) depending on the language standard (C++11/C++14), and, what is crucial, the default constructor in C++14 is now made non-`explicit`.

That change was introduced so that one can say:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> m = {};
```

or:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> foo()
{
    return {};
}
```

which are both semantically equivalent to your code (passing `{}` as the argument of a function call to initialize `std::unordered_map<int,int>`).

That is, in case of a C++11-conforming library, the error is **expected**, as the selected (default) constructor is `explicit`, therefore the code is *ill-formed*:

```
explicit unordered_map(size_type n = /* impl-defined */,
                     const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                     const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                     const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

In case of a C++14-conforming library, the error is **not expected**, as the selected (default) constructor is **not** `explicit`, and the code is *well-formed*:

```
unordered_map();
```

As such, the different behavior you encounter is solely related to the version of libstdc++ and libc++ you are using with different compilers/compiler options.

---

> *Replacing `std::unordered_map` with `std::map` makes the error go away. Why?*

I suspect it's just because `std::map` in the libstdc++ version you are using was already updated for C++14.

---

> *Replacing `foo({})` with `foo({{}})` also makes the error go away. Why?*

Because now this is *copy-list-initialization* `{{}}` with a **non-empty** *braced-init-list* (that is, it has one element inside, initialized with an empty *braced-init-list* `{}`), so the rule from the first phase of § 13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1 (quoted before) that prefers an *initializer-list-constructor* to other ones is applied. That constructor is not `explicit`, hence the call is *well-formed*.

---

> *Replacing `{}` with a non-empty initializer list works as expected in all cases. Why?*

Same as above, the overload resolution ends up with the first phase of § 13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1.

Answer (score 6):

List-initialization for references is defined as follows, [dcl.init.list]/3:

> Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type
>   referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized,
>   depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the
>   reference is bound to that temporary.

So your code fails because

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> m = {};
```

fails. List-initialization for this case is covered through this bullet from [dcl.init.list]/3:

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class
>   type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

So the object's default constructor will be called<sup>1</sup>.
Now to the crucial bits:
In C++11, `unordered_map` had this default constructor<sup>2</sup>:

```
explicit unordered_map(size_type n = /* some value */ ,
                       const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                       const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                       const allocator_type& a = allocator_type());
```

Clearly, calling this `explicit` constructor through copy-list-initialization is ill-formed, [over.match.list]:

> In copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

Since C++14 `unordered_map` declares a default constructor that is non-explicit:

```
unordered_map();
```

So a C++14 standard library implementation should compile this without problems. Presumably libc++ is already updated, but libstdc++ is lagging behind.

---

<sup>1)</sup> [dcl.init]/7:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>  — if `T` is a
>   (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided
>   constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for `T` is called
>   […];

<sup>2)</sup> [class.ctor]/4:

> A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument.