# converting to ‘A’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘A::A(int)’

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc-warning

I am trying to migrate an old C++03 codebase to C++11. But I fail to understand what gcc is warning me about in the following case:

```
% g++ -std=c++03 t.cxx
% g++ -std=c++11 t.cxx
t.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cxx:8:21: warning: converting to ‘A’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘A::A(int)’
    8 | int main() { B b = {}; }
      |                     ^
t.cxx:8:21: note: in C++11 and above a default constructor can be explicit
```

```cpp
struct A {
  explicit A(int i = 42) {}
};
struct B {
  A a;
};
    
int main() {
  B b = {};
  return 0;
}
```

All I am trying to do here is a basic zero initialization. It seems to be legal for C++03, but I fail to understand how to express the equivalent in C++11.

---

For reference, I am using:

```
% g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

Comment: It seems to work/compile in msvc 19.3 with C++14.

Comment: Did you see the `gcc-warning` tag in my question ?

Comment: different case but related https://stackoverflow.com/q/26947704/4117728

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Note that `B` is an aggregate, which is not the case in the linked post.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes its a rather different case, in the other question a change of constructor of `std::unordered_map` comes into play, which is not relevant here. Though large parts of the accepted answers do apply

Comment: @malat You can use `B b = { A{} }` or `B b = { A{0} }` to solve this problem as explained in my answer below. Also, `B b{ A{} }` and `B b{ A{0} }` are also fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given program is **ill-formed** for the reason(s) explained below.

##### C++20

`B` is an **aggregate**. Since you're **not** explicitly initializing `a`, [dcl.init.aggr#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#5) applies:

> 5. For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
> 5.2 Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is **copy-initialized from an empty initializer list** ([dcl.init.list]).

This means that `a` is **copy initialized** from an empty initializer list. In other word, it is as if we're writing:

```
A a = {}; // not valid see reason below
```

Now we move onto [dcl.init.list#3.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#list-3.5):

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is **value-initialized**.

This means that the object will be value initialized.

Now to [value initialize](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#8):

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then
>
>   - if T has either no default constructor ([class.default.ctor]) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is **default-initialized**;

So we move onto [default initialize](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7):

> If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors are considered.The **applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor])**, and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]).
> The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.

Finally from [over.match.ctor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.ctor):

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized, copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type ([dcl.init]), or default-initialized, overload resolution selects the constructor.
> For direct-initialization or default-initialization that is not in the context of copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized.
> **For copy-initialization (including default initialization in the context of copy-initialization), the candidate functions are all the converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class.**
> The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.

This means that only the converting ctor are candidates. And since `A::A(int)` is explicit, it is not a  converting ctor and thus there the set of candidates is empty and the program(`A a ={};`) is ill-formed.

---

Essentially, the reason for the failure is that `A a = {};` is ill-formed.

---

##### Solution

To solve this, we can pass `A{}` or `A{0}` as the initializer inside the list as shown below:

```
B b = { A{} };  //ok now 
B c = { A{0} }; //also ok
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b6G4hve48).

---

##### Note

Note that writing `A a{};` on the other hand is well-formed as this is a direct-initialization context and so it is **direct-list-initialization**.