# Why can a std::tuple not be assigned with an initializer list?

Tags: c++11, stdtuple

I wonder why this choice is made. It would allow to write many functions in a very clear and neat way.. for instance:

```
int greatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    if (b > a)
        std::tie(a, b) = { b, a };
    while (b > 0)
        std::tie(a, b) = { b, a % b };
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does

```
std::tie(a,b) = {b, a};
```

not compile?

`{}` on the right hand side of an assignment can only call a non-explicit constructor of an argument of `operator=`.

The `operator=` overloads available are:

```
tuple& operator=( const tuple& other );
tuple& operator=( tuple&& other );
template< class... UTypes >
tuple& operator=( const tuple<UTypes...>& other );
template< class... UTypes >
tuple& operator=( tuple<UTypes...>&& other );
template< class U1, class U2 >
tuple& operator=( const pair<U1,U2>& p );
template< class U1, class U2 >
tuple& operator=( pair<U1,U2>&& p );
```

The `template` operator overloads cannot deduce their types from `{}` (note: this may change in C++17), leaving:

```
tuple& operator=( const tuple& other );
tuple& operator=( tuple&& other );
```

where `tuple` is `std::tuple<int&, int&>` in this case.

The tuple constructor for `tuple<Ts...>` that perfect forwards element-wise construction is [**explicit**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) (#3 on that list).  `{}` will not call an explicit constructor.

The conditionally non-explicit constructor takes `Ts const&...`; it does not exist if the `Ts` are non-copyable, and `int&` is non-copyable.

So there are no viable types to construct from `{int&, int&}`, and overload resolution fails.

---

Why does the standard not fix this?  Well, we can do it ourselves!

In order to fix this, we'd have to add a special `(Ts...)` non-explicit constructor to `tuple` that only exists if the `Ts` types are all references.

If we write a toy tuple:

```
struct toy {
  std::tuple<int&, int&> data;
  toy( int& a, int& b ):data(a,b) {} // note, non-explicit!
};
toy toy_tie( int& a, int& b ) { return {a,b}; }
```

and use it, you'll notice that

```
    std::tie(a, b) = {b, a};
```

compiles and runs.

However,

```
    std::tie(a, b) = { b, a % b };
```

does not, as `a%b` cannot be bound to `int&`.

We can then augment `toy` with:

```
template<class...>
toy& operator=( std::tuple<int, int> o ) {
    data = o;
    return *this;
}
```

(+ defaulted special member functions.  `template<class...>` ensures it has lower priority than the special member functions, as it should).

This which lets assign-from `{int,int}`.  We then run it and... get the wrong result.  The gcd of `5,20` is `20`.  What went wrong?

```
  toy_tie(a, b) = std::tie( b, a );
```

with both `a` and `b` bound to references is not safe code, and that is what

```
  toy_tie(a, b) = { b, a };
```

does.

In short, doing this right is tricky.  In this case, you need to take a *copy* of the right hand side before assigning to be safe.  Knowing when to take a copy and when not to is also tricky.

Having this work implicitly looks error prone.  So it is, in a sense, accidental that it doesn't work, but fixing it (while possible) looks like a bad idea.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73adcf4a6ce6cf2e).

Comment: great explanation.. I was influenced by python's multiple assignment (e.g. a, b = b, a%b) but to this safely you need to take a copy each time (as Python does)

Answer (score 7):

[`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a *homogeneous* collection of items, while [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is *heterogeneous*. The only case where it makes sense to define a [`std::tuple::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D) for `std::initializer_list` is when the tuple is homogeneous and has the same size as the initializer list, which is a rare occurrence.

[*(Additional information in this question.)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413050/initializing-stdtuple-from-initializer-list)

---

**Solution/workaround**: you can use [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) instead:

```
int greatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    if (b > a)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a);
    while (b > 0)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a % b);
    return a;
}
```

...or `std::tuple`'s constructor in C++17 *(thanks to [Template argument deduction for class templates](http://wg21.link/p0091r3))*:

```
int greatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    if (b > a)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::tuple{b, a};
    while (b > 0)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::tuple{b, a % b};
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `={ blah }` does not always refer to an initializer list; it can be construction.