# How to pass an array to std::make_tuple?

Tags: arrays, c++11, tuples, initializer-list

How to do this:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<double, int[2]> f()
{
    return std::make_tuple(0., {1, 2});
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

> could not convert 'std::make_tuple<{}>()' from 'std::tuple<>' to 'std::tuple'

Can't the compiler figure out what to do?

Answer (score 5):

If you necessary need to use a "compile-time vector", try [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
#include <array>
// ...

std::tuple<double, std::array<int, 2>> f() {
  return std::make_tuple(0., std::array<int, 2>{1, 2});
}
```

> As an aggregate type, it can be initialized with
>   aggregate-initialization given at most N initializers that are
>   convertible to T.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that is not possible. Read this [Initializing std::tuple from initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413050/initializing-stdtuple-from-initializer-list)

Instead, you may choose to pass a ***vector*** like this:

```
std::tuple<double, vector<int>> t = std::make_tuple(0.0, vector<int>{1,3});
```

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki, that "int pointer" example made me even verify with `sizeof` that `int[2]` doesn't decay to a ponter in the tuple. Anyway, for the practical application I'll go with `using MyTuple = std::tuple<double, int[2]>; ... return MyTuple(0., {1, 2});`.